# Xorg cannot detect my screen and I cannot start any desktop manager

Tags: xorg, startup, xserver

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and then I ran the magical command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However contrary to my previous statement, the effect was not so magical. It made my system, which was working properly from install, stop working completely. Well Xorg specifically.

My first attempt was to try and purge my nvidia drivers and reinstall, a task I have done several times, then I tried to change my desktop manager and I installed lightdm, still yeilding no satisfactory results.

My final attempt was to try and remove the xorg.conf, which as it turns out cannot even generate a new config file. The error I get every time I run

```
sudo X -configure
```

is

```
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices
```

So far through my research I have not been able to make heads or tails of it, and have even tried many of the solutions suggested. Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I need this machine working for college.

A bit more info is I am running this on an MSI GE62 6QD Apache Pro

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I had a conflicting debian repository that was replacing some of my core programs, and thus broke everything once I updated.